# XPath find child, where another child of the same node has specific value

Tags: xpath, cucumber

I have 4 other elements the same as below though they differ in title

```
<div id="r7695cf6b-f4a79" class="featureFoo ">
  <div class="overview">
    <h3 class="title">My Library</h3>
    <p class="description">Some description</p>
  </div>
  <div class="foo">
    <form>
      <div id="ra41984bc58005" class="switch label-position-right non-required" aria-describedby="">
        <input name="fooEnabled" type="checkbox" id="r14e560d0-bfbc-476a-a066-cbb3c043006c" checked="" class="">
        <div class="foo-switch">
          <div class="indicator"></div>
        </div>
        <span class="error" title=""></span>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to retrieve the nonhidden input element and to see if it is checked. I have this xpath

```
$x("//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo')][./div/h3[text()='My Library']]//input[contains(@name,'fooEnabled')]")
```

which works in the Chrome console but it does not work in Ruby Cucumber's find() method

```
find(:xpath, "//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo')][./div/h3[text()='My Library']]//input[contains(@name,'fooEnabled')]")
```

Is there more conversion that needs to be done to the xpath so it will work in cucumber's find() or could there be a better approach to this?

Comment: Try using "and" instead =>   "//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo') and ./div/h3[text()='My Library']]//input[contains(@name,'fooEnabled')]"

Comment: @Borna `"//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo') and ./div/h3[text()='My Library']]"` part is fine either way. By calling .text and puts, it will print the description "Some description", still I can't get it to switch over to the other child node though. It seems that `./div/h3[text()="My Library"]` isn't doing a look ahead type filter but is actually traversing it down as a path, if that makes sense.

Comment: Currently I am trying to do `find(:xpath, "//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo') and ./div/h3[text()='My Library']]/../div[@class='foo']")` but am getting `Unable to find xpath" ElementNotFound

Comment: and if you remove unnecessary "dot" like so `//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo')][div/h3[text()='My Library']]//input[contains(@name,'fooEnabled')]`

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk without the "dot" it throws the error `"Unable to find xpath"`

Comment: Strange, it is valid XPath...

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk Sorry, it is valid yes, by Unable to find xpath I forgot to mention the ElementNotFound part.

Comment: and if you remove this part, will it work? `//div[contains(@class, 'featureFoo')][div/h3]//input[contains(@name,'fooEnabled')]`